# Android Studio NullPointerException on a Defined Button on Class

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception

I use Android studio and I only know basic java.
I know I need to declare the Widgets on Class to use it in another function but it still gives nullreference error.

```
package com.uruskan.shock.kultureventbase;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements 
View.OnClickListener {
TextView tv;
Button bYemek, bSleep, bAttack;
int sayac = 0;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.event_date);
    Button bYemek = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button); //yemek ye
    Button bSleep = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2); //uyu
    Button bAttack = (Button) findViewById(R.id.attack); // saldır
    bYemek.setOnClickListener(this);
    bSleep.setOnClickListener(this);
    bAttack.setOnClickListener(this);
    Karakter k = new Karakter();
    k.hareketSayisi = 10;
    k.kilo = 10;
    k.saldiriGücü = 100;

}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    if (v.getId() == bAttack.getId()) {
        //Attack Code
        tv.setText("Attack ");
    } else if (v.getId() == bSleep.getId()) {
        //sleep code
        tv.setText("Sleeping Rrrrrr !");
    } else if (v.getId() == bYemek.getId()) {
        //eat code
        tv.setText("Narcissus get her, for a dinner..");
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: Remove `Button` from `Button bAttack` with your code you defined a local variable which shadows the field and your field remains null.(the same applies to `bSleep` and `bYemek`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update your code:

```
bYemek = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button); //yemek ye
bSleep = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2); //uyu
bAttack = (Button) findViewById(R.id.attack); // saldır
```

Comment: Why i should do that ? (Oh okay it becomes a local variable.)

Comment: @ReazMurshed it lools like we posted at same time

Comment: Ya. I think so. :)

Answer (score 0):

You're initializing your `Button` variables locally which is out of scope when they are being referenced from the `onClick` function and this is why you're getting the `NullPointerException`.

So as you've declared the buttons as public variables, you need to assign the variables like this.

```
bYemek = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button); //yemek ye
bSleep = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2); //uyu
bAttack = (Button) findViewById(R.id.attack); // saldır
```

And in the `onClick` function, you can simply do this.

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.button:
            tv.setText("Narcissus get her, for a dinner..");
            return;
        case R.id.button2:
            tv.setText("Sleeping Rrrrrr !");
            return;
        case R.id.attack:
            tv.setText("Attack ");
            return;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks.I thought about using switch-case too.